# React native link creates duplicated entries

Tags: android, react-native

I don't know why `react-native link` is creating duplicated entries in `MainApplication.java` (at imports and in getPackages function) and in `app\build.gradle` the `compile project` entry is not being added, but if I run again the command, I receive the same message instead of that the module is already linked.

When I run `react-native link`, I receive the messages that the module has been linked successfully on Android (duplicated) and in iOS it was already linked.

[image: react-native link result]

Comment: I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Many users are encountering the issue on Android (me included). It is due to difference between iOs and Android code-signin.

There is an opened (and recent) PR for this on the react-native project https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/18131 - hopefully it will be merged soon!

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue when I tried to link a library to my code. On running the react-native link command, it displayed that the library has been linked successfully though the entries were never created. What I did was to manually modify these 3 files:

1. android/settings.gradle: Add the module using include() and specify the path of your project directory.

   ```
   include ':your_package_name'
   project(':your_package_name').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../node_modules/your_package_name')
   ```
2. android/app/build.gradle: Add the compile statement

   ```
   compile project(':your_package_name')
   ```
3. android/app/src/main/java/[..project_name..]/MainApplication.java: Import the package and make sure that the getPackages() is returning your package along with the previous ones.

Would have answered you better if you specified the name of the required library

Comment: Hi Utkarsh, I am already doing these steps, but it should be automatically. The packages I am using you can see them at the screenshot I am providing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was related with RN version and local libraries.

I solved it by removing the duplicated libraries on Xcode.

Here is [link](https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n/issues/43)

Hope it give you some help.